# Multiple editable areas

Tags: theme-development

I am new to WordPress development and I am editing an existing theme. Basically, I created a [custom template for Pages](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/). I learnt that the editable content of the template is defined by the

```
the_content()
```

function.

The problem is that I want to have more areas for the user to add content. Is that possible?

here's is an example:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div style="mystyle">

                <div class="center-block " style="someotherstyle">
                        // i want text here
                        <?php the_content(); ?> // this works

                </div>
            </div>

            // want also content here
            // tried the_content() but it's not working twice.
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add more meta boxes - with simple text field editors or TinyMCE editors with more functions - in admin, and then call those meta boxes in your page template.

This is a very common thing to do in WordPress, both in a UX sense for the user to be able to add content, and because - as you have discovered as a site admin and theme developer - the function `the_content()` can only be used once in the loop and wasn't designed to be used multiple times.

Best thing to do is take a look at some plugins that enable you to add and configure the display of more meta boxes. The most popular and extensible is https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

And do a search for other similar questions: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=advanced+custom+fields regarding that plugin.